# how to access folder outside of htdocs with php

Tags: php, xampp, htdocs

i have program, the log file address like that

> C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\program-folder\Logs

and now i want read this log file (text) with php
how can assign address to open this file?

Answer (score 0):

PHP run by Apache cannot access files outside of the site root for obvious security reasons.  If you can't move the log file, you could look to use a symlink to make it accessible.

Based on the path you've given I'm assuming you're using Windows.  Here's a guide to [symbolic links in Windows](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/).